# Meaning of the word "clutch" in "And bones, well, they're pretty clutch."

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I have come upon the sentence with the word that I cannot get in [Crash Course Anatomy & Physiology](https://youtu.be/rDGqkMHPDqE). It is at around [46 seconds](https://youtu.be/rDGqkMHPDqE?t=46s). Here is the context:

> Astronauts often experience things like trouble sleeping, puffy faces, and loss of muscle mass, but perhaps the most serious damage a microgravity environment causes is to the bones. And bones, well, they're pretty **clutch**.

I have looked up the meanings of the adjective *clutch* in a bunch of dictionaries, but none seems to fit.

Comment: I would love the know the next sentence (but would rather not have to watch the video).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an odd usage in my opinion. From M-W

> [Definition of clutch for English Language Learners](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clutch)
>       : happening during a very important or critical time especially in a sports competition
>       : able to perform well in a very important or critical situation especially in a sports competition

In this case, he's trying to be funny. You can tell by his delivery. The usage of the word is suggesting that bones are handy, or useful, in a critical situation. But that's misleading. The bones themselves are critical. Without bones, you wouldn't be able to live.

Comment: That is strange to me. I looked up the word in Urban Dictionary and got kind of the same meanings.